# Cookie alternative ASP

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

What can i use if Cookies are disabled in ASP classic?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's the code: `<p class="warning">You seem to have cookies disabled. Please enable cookies in order to use this site.</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friendly notification to tell them to allow permission for cookies is the best option usually, otherwise you will be spending a lot of time maintaining a difficult to use system to cater for a minority of visitors.

Because HTTP is stateless by nature, it's hard to maintain a state between page requests if the client explicitly blocks them.

One way it can be overcome, but comes with it's own problems and I highly suggest you don't try it, is pass a query string parameter to every internal link identifying the user.  This would be incredibly hard to maintain and comes with a host of security concerns.